# How to use a gem in Rails 3 without referencing it in the Gemfile

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems, bundler

I'm wondering how to make a gem accessible in a Rails 3 app without putting a reference to it in the gemfile. I want to do this with ruby-debug (I'm using [ruby-debug19](http://github.com/mark-moseley/ruby-debug)). I use this to debug, but not everybody on my team does and forcing the dependency just so I can use it doesn't seem very diplomatic. Is there another way?

If it ends up mattering, I'm using Rails3, Bundler 1.0.0, Ruby 1.9.2, RVM, OSX Snow Leopard

On a side note, I had thought about using the gemfile group feature, but this doesn't feel right either. Groups seem great for things like factory_girl where there is an actual dependency albeit only in specfic environments, but with ruby-debug there is no real need for it to be there unless you want to use it.

Comment: I am determined to figure this out for myself, and will share if I do. IMO Bundler is the worst thing to have ever happened to Rails.

Answer (score 3):

This is really ugly and it does not pull it out of your gemfile, but I do this in my Gemfile so I can use 2 different sources for a gem in different environments:

```
if ENV['MY_RDEBUG_VAR'] == "i_want_to_use_rdebug"
  gem "ruby-debug"
end
```

Just make it an obscure environment variable that only you would set on your system.  That way, your coworkers will not have the env var set and the gem will never be installed or loaded for them.

Answer (score 2):

AFAIK you can't because Rails 3 isolates system Gems.

My suggestion is to add the Gem in the Gemfile with the `:require => false` option so it is included, installed but never loaded.
Then, in your app, require the gem manually.

Or you can try to bundle it in your project, within the vendor folder (there should be a folder for Gems) and ignore the specific gem folder in your SCM so that your co-workers won't be affected.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I'd really hate to even require the installation of the gem though. The installation of this particular gem isn't always straight forward and the `bundle install` command is then subject to fail as a result :(.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up adding the following code to a rails initializer and ignoring it in the .git/info/exclude file.

```
$: << Bundler.bundle_path.join("gems", "ruby-debug19-0.11.6", "cli")
$: << Bundler.bundle_path.join("gems", "ruby-debug-base19-0.11.24", "lib")
$: << Bundler.bundle_path.join("gems", "linecache19-0.5.11", "lib")
$: << Bundler.bundle_path.join("gems", "columnize-0.3.1", "lib")
require 'ruby-debug'
```

While this works, I don't know if anybody should actually do this, accepting the fact that these dependencies need to be placed in the gem file is probably best.

Comment: Use this solution at your own risk. I believe it has stopped working for me in a subsequent version of RVM. Now-a-days I add the ruby-debug to the development group in my gemfile.

Answer (score 0):

This is my own solution to using ruby_debug with both ruby 1.8 and 1.9

```
if RUBY_VERSION.include?('1.9')
  ruby_debug = 'ruby-debug19'  # new branch for ruby-debug that supports 1.9
else
  ruby_debug = 'ruby-debug'
  gem 'fastercsv' # ruby 1.9 bundles FasterCSV now
end


group :test do
  gem 'webrat'
  gem "factory_girl"
  gem 'shoulda'

  # gem 'redgreen'
  gem 'autotest-rails'
  gem 'autotest-fsevent'
  gem 'autotest'  
  gem ruby_debug
end

group :development do
  gem ruby_debug
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this doesn't cover some other cases where it would be nice if there was a clean way to accomplish this -- `autotest-growl` and `autotest-fsevent` come to mind, as well as lots of things I require/rescue in my `.irbrc` for a nicer experience that I don't want to force on everyone, like wirble and hirb -- but specifically for `ruby-debug`, the [ruby-debug-wrapper gem](http://rubygems.org/gems/ruby-debug-wrapper) is helpful if testing against multiple Ruby versions is part of your pain.

If you want to avoid installing *any* version of `ruby-debug`, I think options others have suggested are the only ways currently.